# How do I validate Tic-Tac-Toe game ending scenario

Tags: python, function

I have created a simple program for tic tac toe. I need help on last part of the program. the program checks if the game is over - there are four possible verdicts: the game should continue, or the game ends with a tie, your win, or the computer's win; Can some one please help.

function `Victory` checks for row, column and diagonal values. If row , column or diagonal value is equal to `'X'` or `'O'` then program should print `computer's win` or `User's win`. But I am not sure where to call this in `Update_board`. Can someone please help.

```
import random


def board():
    "Creating Board dictionary"
    dic_board = {}
    v = 1
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            k = str(i) + str(j)
            dic_board[k] = v
            v += 1
    update_board(dic_board)



def draw_board(board):
    """Draw board"""
    for i in range(3):
        print('+' + '-' * 5 + '+' + '-' * 5 + '+' + '-' * 5 + '+', end='')
        print()
        print('|' + ' ' * 5 + '|' + ' ' * 5 + '|' + ' ' * 5 + '|')
        for j in range(3):
            k = str(i) + str(j)
            print('| ' + str(board[k]) + ' ' * 3, end='')
        print('|')
        print('|' + ' ' * 5 + '|' + ' ' * 5 + '|' + ' ' * 5 + '|')
    print('+' + '-' * 5 + '+' + '-' * 5 + '+' + '-' * 5 + '+', end='')
    print()

def update_board(board):
    """the first move belongs to the computer -
    it always puts its first 'X' in the middle of the board that is at 5;"""
    total_moves = 0
    flag = True  #Flag = True for computer's move and False for user's move
    while total_moves < 9 :
        available_num = [v for k, v in board.items() if v not in ('X','O')]
        if flag :
            if total_moves == 0:
                Update_moves(board, 'Comp', 5)
                flag = False
                draw_board(board)

            else:

                num = random.choice(available_num)
                Update_moves(board, 'Comp', num)
                flag = False
                draw_board(board)
        else:
            try:
                s = str(available_num)
                val = int(input('Select Number '+ s + ': '))
                Update_moves(board, 'User', val)
                flag = True
            except:
                print('Invalid Input!!')
        total_moves += 1
    return board


def Update_moves(board, moves,val):
    "Updating borad as per input"
    key_to_update = [k for k, v in board.items() if v == val]
    if moves == 'Comp':
        board[key_to_update[0]] = 'X'
    elif moves == 'User':
        board[key_to_update[0]] = 'O'
    return board

def Victory(board,sign):
    message = ''
    message = row_status(board,sign,message)
    message = column_status(board,sign,message)
    message = digonals_status(board,sign,message)
    return message



def row_status(board,sign,message):
    """checking for Horizontal row"""
    if board['00'] == board['01'] == board['02'] == sign or \
            board['10'] == board['11'] == board['12'] == sign or \
            board['20'] == board['21'] == board['22'] == sign:
        if sign == 'X':
            message = 'computer win !!'
        elif sign == 'O':
            message = 'Your win !!'
    return message

def column_status(board,sign,message):
    """checking for verticle column """
    if board['00'] == board['10'] == board['20'] == sign or \
            board['01'] == board['11'] == board['21'] == sign or \
            board['02'] == board['12'] == board['22'] == sign:
        if sign == 'X':
            message = 'computer win !!'
        elif sign == 'O':
            message = 'Your win !!'
    return message

def digonals_status(board,sign,message):
    """checking for digonals """
    if board['00'] == board['11'] == board['22'] == sign or \
       board['02'] == board['11'] == board['20'] == sign :
        if sign == 'X':
            message = 'computer win !!'
        elif sign == 'O':
            message = 'Your win !!'
    return message




print(board())
```

Comment: Generally, functions should be lowercase and Classes should be uppercase.

Comment: You need to check for victory after every move.  So, just before the end of your `while` loop.  Note that if the user gave invalid input, you don't want to bump `total_moves`.  You should probably do a `continue` there.

Comment: @TimRoberts I tried putting victory just before the end of while loop but print the message without drawing updated board.

Comment: If you want the final board printed after the "victory" message, then for gosh sakes call `draw_board` after you print the message.  Isn't that obvious?

Comment: Thank you.  I completed code and it is working fine now.